# x axis ticks not appearing in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I’m working on a bar chart using d3.js (v5), and I’m running into some trouble getting the xAxis ticks to appear. Relevant code is as follows, full repo is at (https://github.com/dylanesque/BarChart):

```
  const dateParser = d3.timeParse('%Y');
  const xAccessor = (d) => dateParser(d[0]);

  const xScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataset, xAccessor))
    .range([0, dimensions.boundedWidth]);

 const xAxisGenerator = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale).ticks(14);
   const xAxis = bounds
     .append('g')
     .call(xAxisGenerator)
     .attr('id', 'x-axis')
     .style('transform', `translateY(${dimensions.boundedHeight}px)`);

   const xAxisLabel = xAxis
     .append('text')
     .attr('x', dimensions.boundedWidth / 2)
     .attr('y', dimensions.margin.bottom - 10)
     .attr('fill', 'black')
     .style('font-size', '1.4em');
```

What's strange about this is that I'm using the same basic approach on another d3 project I'm working on (https://github.com/dylanesque/Scatter), and it's working as expected there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that this line:

`const parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y');`

needed to be this line:

`const parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');`

From the d3.js `time-format` docs:

> Parsing is strict: if the specified string does not exactly match the associated specifier, this method returns null. For example, if the associated specifier is %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ, then the string "2011-07-01T19:15:28Z" will be parsed as expected, but "2011-07-01T19:15:28", "2011-07-01 19:15:28" and "2011-07-01" will return null.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have no `text()` specified, your other codes in github all have the `text()` entry except the `xAxisLabel`

```
   const xAxisLabel = xAxis
     .append('text')
     .attr('x', dimensions.boundedWidth / 2)
     .attr('y', dimensions.margin.bottom - 10)
     .attr('fill', 'black')
     .style('font-size', '1.4em')
     .text("WHAT"); // the text to show
```

Comment: Whoops, I had the verbiage wrong, my issue is ticks, not labels